# "while loop" not breaking (using Python)

Tags: python, while-loop

This is my code :

```python
#Choose Report
def chooseReport():
    print "Choose a report."
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Enter A or B: ")
        if choice == 'a' or choice == 'A':
            reportA()
            break
        elif choice == 'b' or choice == 'B':
            reportB()
            break
        else:
            continue
```

When I input either `a` or `b`, it just asks me to `"Enter A or B"` again. It doesn't go to the functions its supposed to.

Any idea why is this?

Comment: try choice.lower().strip()

Comment: On a side note, the `else: continue` is totally redundant here.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program to see what does `choice` have?

Comment: `break` will only break out of the if condition. Use a condition variable to break out the loop

Comment: Do you call the `chooseReport` function inside some loop?

Comment: Well maybe the issue is with `reportA()` or `reportB()` methods because the code works fine and breaks

Answer (score 2):

```
def chooseReport():
    print "Choose a report."
    t=True                                        # t starts at true
    while t:
        choice = raw_input("Enter A or B: ")
        if choice == 'a' or choice == 'A':
            reportA()
            t=False               # t turns false to break out of loop
        elif choice == 'b' or choice == 'B':
            reportB()
            t=False
```

Try this. It keeps looping when t is true and stops when t is false. The problem might also be in reportA or reportB or how you are calling chooseReport.

Comment: What is wrong with his break statements? Am I missing something?

Comment: This does not work? Is there any problem with 't' variable scope?

Answer (score 2):

The code is perfect, except a redundant else, as mentioned in the comment. Are you entering `a` (a + space)  rather than simply `a` (a without space) ? The problem is in the input that you are providing and not in the code!

Answer (score 2):

First, your code works fine, the most probably error is that you are writing a wrong input (e.g: with more characters). To solve that you could use `"a" in choice or "A" in choice`. But if it isn't working... keep reading.

It's seems that `break` isn't affecting the `while loop`, I don't have python 2 so I am not very sure why (in python 3 [after change `raw_input` to `input` and `print` to `print()`] your code works perfect). So you should use the condition of the `while` to break it.

`while True` work theorically for ever because each time the code is executed it checks the condition -`True`-  and because it's true it keeps looping.
You could manipulate that condition in order to break the loop (don't allow execute again its code).

For example you could use this:

```
#Choose Report
def chooseReport():
    print "Choose a report."
    allow = True    # allow start as True so the while will work
    while allow:
        choice = raw_input("Enter A or B: ")
        if choice.lower().strip() == "a":    # This is better. .lower() make "A" > "a", and .strip() delete " a " to "a", and "a/n" to "a".
            reportA()
            allow = False   # allow now is False, the while won't execute again
        elif choice.lower().strip() == "b":
            reportB()
            allow = False   # allow now is False, the while won't execute again
        # The else is complete redundant, you don't need it
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `raw_input()`. It returns a string but maybe this string is `"a "` or `"a\n"` though you have entered `"a"` or `"b"`.

I would do this:

```
def chooseReport():
    print "Choose a report."
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Enter A or B: ")
        if "a" in choice or "A" in choice:
            reportA()
            break
        elif "b" in choice or "B" in choice: 
            reportB()
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried your code in the following script, it works fine both on Linux and on Windows.

```
def reportA():
    print "AAAAA"

def reportB():
    print "BBBBB"

#Choose Report
def chooseReport():
    print "Choose a report."
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Enter A or B: ")
        if choice == 'a' or choice == 'A':
            reportA()
            break
        elif choice == 'b' or choice == 'B':
            reportB()
            break
        else:
            continue


chooseReport();
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine. I think you call your chooseReport() function in a loop or your input has extra characters and if conditions didn't satisfied.