# While Loop continues even if the condition has been met (using Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

This is my code:

```
while True: 
    chosenUser = raw_input("Enter a username: ")
    with open("userDetails.txt", "r") as userDetailsFile:    
        for line in userDetailsFile:
            if chosenUser in line:
                print "\n"
                print chosenUser, "has taken previous tests. "
                break
            else:
                print "That username is not registered."
```

Even after entering a username and it outputting results, the loop continues and asks me to input the username again.

I have recently asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358686/while-loop-not-breaking-using-python) but got it working myself. This one is not working no matter what I try.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Note: `userDetailsFile` is a text file that is in the program earlier.

The problem might be obvious but I'm quite new to Python so I'm sorry if I'm wasting anyone's time.

Comment: `break` applies to the `for` loop and terminates it early. It does not affect the `while True` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, the primary problem is that the `break` only breaks from the inner `for` loop, not from the outer `while` loop, which can be fixed using e.g. a boolean variable or `return`.

But unless you want the "not registered" line to be printed for *every* line that does not contain the user's name, you should use [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) instead of `if/else`. However, instead of using a `for` loop, you could also just use `next` with a generator expression to get the right line (if any).

```
while True: 
    chosenUser = raw_input("Enter a username: ")
    with open("userDetails.txt", "r") as userDetailsFile:
        lineWithUser = next((line for line in userDetailsFile if chosenUser in line), None)
        if lineWithUser is not None:
            print "\n"
            print chosenUser, "has taken previous tests. "
            break # will break from while now
        else:
            print "That username is not registered."
```

Or if you do not actually need the `lineWithUser`, just use `any`:

```
while True: 
    chosenUser = raw_input("Enter a username: ")
    with open("userDetails.txt", "r") as userDetailsFile:
        if any(chosenUser in line for line in userDetailsFile):
            print "\n"
            print chosenUser, "has taken previous tests. "
            break # will break from while now
        else:
            print "That username is not registered."
```

This way, the code is also much more compact and easier to read/understand what it's doing.

Comment: That seems quite complex and I'm unfamiliar with this. I'm getting a syntax error in: `lineWithUser = next((line in userDetailsFile if chosenUser in line), None)` The syntax error is the `line)` brcaket.

Comment: @Programmer12 There was a mistake in the `next` generator; however, on closer inspection you don't even need it, `any` is enough, making it much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to work around this is to make the outer `while` alterable by using a boolean variable, and toggling it:

```
loop = True
while loop:
    for x in y:
        if exit_condition:
            loop = False
            break
```

That way you can stop the outer loop from within an inner one.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` breaks out the the inner `for` loop only.
Better put everything in a function and stop your `while` loop with a `return`:

```
def main():
    while True: 
        chosenUser = raw_input("Enter a username: ")
        with open("userDetails.txt", "r") as userDetailsFile:    
            for line in userDetailsFile:
                if chosenUser in line:
                    print "\n"
                    print chosenUser, "has taken previous tests. "
                    return # stops the while loop
             print "That username is not registered."

main()
print 'keep going here'
```

Comment: That seems to completely end my whole program though even if I have functions after it?

Comment: This will not work properly, if `else` should actually be after the `for` (to execute if the for finished normally) but that won't work with `return`.

Comment: @Programmer12 Why should it exit your program? You can write code after `main()`. You can also use different name than `main` if you prefer.

Comment: No, sorry. It's still completely ending my program. (I'm using Python 2.7 if that has anything to do with it?)

Comment: I have this after my code:  ` print "\n", "You can now exit the quiz or choose another report."
    while True:
        userDecision = raw_input("Choose 'report' or 'exit'").lower()
        if userDecision == 'report':
            chooseReport()
            break
        elif userDecision == "quit":
            sys.exit()`

Comment: It's not printing any of it?